# Migrating ExpressionEngine to Drupal 7 DONE but Password is not working

Tags: drupal, migration, expressionengine

I have migrate EE users in to Drupal using user_save() function but when users are trying to login with EE password they can not able to login and getting password is wrong. I have used below code to migrate data.

```
foreach($result as $eeUser) {

    $drupalUser = user_load_by_name($eeUser['username']);

    if (!$drupalUser) {
        $user_array = array(
            "name" => $eeUser['username'],
            "pass" => $eeUser['password'],
            "mail" => $eeUser['email'],
            "status" => 1
        );
        user_save($account, $user_array);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EE does not store passwords.  It stores *hashes* of passwords, actually I think it stores *salted hashes* of passwords.

So what you have migrated into Drupal is a hash not the password.

I believe Drupal also stores hashed passwords rather than the passwords themselves.

If your install of Drupal were to use *the exact same* hashing method as EE only then could your users login using their existing password.

I think you would be better off asking your existing users to reset their passwords.  I'm not a Drupal guy but maybe you can loop through your users and send them all an email with a reset password link.